# Jquery Change background colour on Nav link mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, mouseover

I want to change the color of background when I hover on different links in my nav menu. Say, link one.. the background goes to red, nav 2 the background goes to blue, nav 3 the background goes to green etc. But now, when i am on those pages, background to be the same as when the mouse hover over the links. So page 1 background will be red, page 2 = blue, page 3 = green etc.

Answer (score 1):

Store the background-color info for all the links in cookies and when you visit one of these pages, get all the cookies and compare their values for your current page and set the background of that color.

For example when you hover over link1 set a cookie similar to this pair of string "link1color": "red" and so on.
When you visit one of these pages get the cookies find the matching cookie for the page and get the **background-color** and update the background.

Comment: Thanks alot I will try something like this, I have never used cookies before so this will be good to try.

Comment: This is something tough method, you can use more simple js method then this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
<a href="#" class="change-bg-color" data-bg-color="#ff0000">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="change-bg-color" data-bg-color="#00ff00">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="change-bg-color" data-bg-color="#0000ff">Link 3</a>

<script>
    $('a.change-bg-color').hover(function(){
        // Change you color
        $(body).css('background-color', this.getAttribute('data-bg-color') );
    },function(){
        // Back to the original color
        $(body).css('background-color', '#fff' ); // Supposing that #fff is your default bg color
    });
</script>
```

And if you want the "Link 1", "Link 2" and "Link 3" pages to have a different background color, the best way to do it should be to have a page-specific CSS class. It doesn't require javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Store your background color in an array and change value accordingly from an array value with the help of js/jquery according to your need on your current page, Because if array is defined globally then you can access anywhere within your application with fast access and low memory.

Comment: The array will not persist on navigation over different pages.

Comment: So you are suggesting to `pollute` the global environment with variables?

Comment: for define globally you can create it in an one js file and just attach it in your index.html header section. or if values are less then an small array you can place in index file

Comment: no keep all variable values in an array here is the link just need to place variable name at the place of index values like :http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Comment: Are you sure this gonna work. Defining variables globally does not mean you can access the same variable from different pages even in the same application.

Comment: As soon as you leave a page all variable are vanished.

Comment: no dear i said you previously...... I used in my many applications and all are online(Phonegap applications) and working fine without any complaint.

Comment: Can you please give some live example of it?

Comment: what do you mean? you need application name or what?

Comment: Any live demo of any of your application or at-least a link to some other application using this technique.

Comment: how can you get this much of point..... you didn't attach js file in your index.html, you didn't use an array or what? How you are not understanding unless you are a programmer and get good points here, why?

Comment: I cant write here because of my company's security policy otherwise i can send you more than thirty mobile site's name

Comment: Your last two comments explained it all to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Approach :

1. Have three different classes in your CSS - say bkBlue, bkRed, bkGreen

   .bkBlue
   {
   background-color : 'blue'
   }
2. Using on hover event, change the class applied to the link using addClass and removeClass.
3. Store the current class value in a session variable.
4. add the class from the session variable to the current page.

Answer (score 0):

And one another method is keep different hover classes with different id/class, if nav is not in large numbers and attach that classes with your particular nav hover. I hope you understand because this is the easiest way. Gud luck